# Is The ASP.NET "DataSourceHelper" Class Essentially The Dal?

Tags: asp.net

I've seen the a class named DataSourceHelper, with an attribute of DataObject(true), in a couple of modern open source ASP.NET projects.

Is the use of such a class now an ASP.NET idiom, and if so is it the equivalent of the DAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only use I have seen for this is internal to the .NET framework , the only method it implements is the following:

```
System.Web.UI.DataSourceHelper.GetResolvedDataSource(object o, string data_member)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
System.Web.UI.DataSourceResolver.ResolveDataSource(object o, string data_member)
```

look here for a full codes (in mono project):

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid546A9F9796B7DC3E5B9C739D76B5C18F8C27B9CB.aspx?s=DataSourceHelper#L2

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid6346172865991F983A0546451DF02B2E2F868D8D.aspx?s=DataSourceResolver#L2

Comment: This should be the answer, if not exactly, plz let me know.